# Pandas: How to use LocIndexer?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to use a Locindexer object to select a subset of a dataframe.

For example

`var = df.loc(df['rating'] == 4)`

Returns as

`pandas.core.indexing._LocIndexer`

How do I use a LocIndexer to select the a subset of my dataframe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are calling it as a function. For indexing, you use [].

```
df.loc[df['rating'] == 4]
```

would return the row/rows in which value of column rating is 4.

Comment: Yes that's it. What is the purpose of calling it as a function?

Comment: Loc is a method of the dataframe object df which means the method loc is called FOR the df. Further the [] necessary because it is the notation for selection by label with loc as you can see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any problems selecting a subset using the code below.

```
subset = df.loc[(df['rating'] == 4)]
```

Comment: It does select it the way I want, but I don't know what to do with the _LocIndexer object.

Answer (score -1):

Furthermore if you have selected the row with:

```
subset = df.loc[(df['rating'] == 4)]
```

you can acces a special column of this row with

1.

```
df.loc[(df['rating'] == 4)]["column]
```

2.

```
subset["column"]
```